# Create a scheme for Packages, Products and Services

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: Packages, Products and Services:

```
create table dbo.Packages ( 
  Id int identity not null
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
)

create table dbo.Products ( 
  Id int identity not null
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
)

create table dbo.Services ( 
  Id int identity not null
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
)
```

I need to relate the 3 tables to fulfill the following requirements:

1. A package consists of a mix of products and services;
2. All products can be included in a package;
3. Not all services can be included in a package;
4. A product or service can be included in many packages;
5. A product or a service cannot appear twice in the same package.

I am not sure how to build this scheme specially because of (3) and (5).

Probably I will need Table inheritance, Many to Many relationship and some kind of Index for (5)?

Could someone, please, advice me on this?

**UPDATE**

One option to Frazz suggestion would be to use Component base table as follows so a Service can have the ComponentId as null. Just one more option ...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Packages ( 
  id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  name NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Components ( 
  id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Products ( 
  id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  component_id INT NOT NULL,
  name NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Services ( 
  id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  component_id INT NULL,
  name NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Package_Components (
  package_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Packages(id),
  component_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Components(id)
  PRIMARY KEY (package_id, component_id)
);
```

Comment: You need to add 2 tables. Package_Products and Package_Services implement many to many relationships between... well you guessed it :) These tables should have a primary key (package_id, product_id) and (package_id, service_id)... this key guarantees (5). The two tables guarantee all the rest except (3).

Comment: (3) is a strange requirement... how do you know which services cannot be included in which packages? Is there some sort of rule or just some combinations to exclude?

Comment: @Frazz That is one point ... I can have a column in Service saying "CanBeIncludeInPackage" or I was looking for table inheritance. I mean a Package would be a mix of Component and a Component would be a base table for Services and Products so each one would have a ComponentId which could be null when a Service cannot be included in a Package. Not sure about this to be honest

Comment: I'd rather go with a boolean that explicitly states what it's purpose is... than with a nullable id column that seems much more obscure and that you may have to handle as an exception in many other queries.

Comment: This last solution has its own difficulties. How do you ensure that there are no two Products/Services with the same component_id? You can use a unique key on Products and Services and that avoids just part of the problem. To ensure that you do not have a Product with the same component_id as a Service, you will need a trigger anyway, don't you think?

Comment: @Frazz You are right. Not an easy problem to solve ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should solve most of what you are asking (tested on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b197)):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Packages ( 
  id   INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  name NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Products ( 
  id   INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  name NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Services ( 
  id              INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  name            NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  can_be_packaged BIT          NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Package_Products (
  package_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Packages (id),
  product_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Products (id)
  PRIMARY KEY (package_id, product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Package_Services (
  package_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Packages (id),
  service_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Services (id)
  PRIMARY KEY (package_id, service_id)
);
```

The two additional tables Package_Products and Package_Services implement the many to many relationships you need for (1), (2) and (4). Their primary keys enforce (5).

What is left is your requirement (3). You said that this depends exclusively on the service, so the additional BIT column can_be_packaged is a good way to handle the requirement. But then you need to enforce it.

The problem is that you cannot execute an SQL statement in a CHECK constraint. So the only solution I see is to have a TRIGGER FOR INSERT and a TRIGGER FOR UPDATE on the Package_Services table. These triggers should execute a SELECT on the Services table and check that the can_be_packaged bit is 1.

Comment: Very well written

Comment: @Frazz Just added an update with the Base table as an option. Still don't know which one to choose. Probably yours.